# State Abbr to full names and search based on like

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column state that have values like

```
california
IL
north Carolina
TX
Dc
```

mixed values abbr and full names

and doing search with like using full state names

how do I convert abbr to full name and do like search based on full names all in lowercase

Comment: You have to have a mapping table that maps abbreviated names to full names and search using the full name values. Or even better, do a one off exercise and change abbreviated names to their full counterpart and implement data quality controls preventing abbreviated names appearing in your data going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Man, this data need urgent normalization!

If normalization is not possible, I devised a fiddle with a possible solution here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf3ef0/1

Given a dummy table

```
create table Dummy(
  id int,
  state varchar(255)
);

insert into Dummy values(1, 'AL');
insert into Dummy values(2, 'Alabama');
insert into Dummy values(3, 'Alaska');
```

To look for data given `state like '%ala%'`, the query shall be:

```
select *
from
    Dummy
        inner join us_states
        on(
             us_states.code = Dummy.state
          or us_states.name = Dummy.state
        )
 where us_states.name like '%ala%'
```

Given the pre-existing table with all `us_states`:

```
create table us_states(
    code varchar(2),
    name varchar(255)
);

insert into us_states
select *
from
    (
        select 'AL' as code, 'Alabama' as name union all
        select 'AK' as code, 'Alaska' as name union all
        select 'AS' as code, 'American Samoa' as name union all
        select 'AZ' as code, 'Arizona' as name union all
        select 'AR' as code, 'Arkansas' as name union all
        select 'CA' as code, 'California' as name union all
        select 'CO' as code, 'Colorado' as name union all
        select 'CT' as code, 'Connecticut' as name union all
        select 'DE' as code, 'Delaware' as name union all
        select 'DC' as code, 'District of Columbia' as name union all
        select 'FM' as code, 'Federated States of Micronesia' as name union all
        select 'FL' as code, 'Florida' as name union all
        select 'GA' as code, 'Georgia' as name union all
        select 'GU' as code, 'Guam' as name union all
        select 'HI' as code, 'Hawaii' as name union all
        select 'ID' as code, 'Idaho' as name union all
        select 'IL' as code, 'Illinois' as name union all
        select 'IN' as code, 'Indiana' as name union all
        select 'IA' as code, 'Iowa' as name union all
        select 'KS' as code, 'Kansas' as name union all
        select 'KY' as code, 'Kentucky' as name union all
        select 'LA' as code, 'Louisiana' as name union all
        select 'ME' as code, 'Maine' as name union all
        select 'MH' as code, 'Marshall Islands' as name union all
        select 'MD' as code, 'Maryland' as name union all
        select 'MA' as code, 'Massachusetts' as name union all
        select 'MI' as code, 'Michigan' as name union all
        select 'MN' as code, 'Minnesota' as name union all
        select 'MS' as code, 'Mississippi' as name union all
        select 'MO' as code, 'Missouri' as name union all
        select 'MT' as code, 'Montana' as name union all
        select 'NE' as code, 'Nebraska' as name union all
        select 'NV' as code, 'Nevada' as name union all
        select 'NH' as code, 'New Hampshire' as name union all
        select 'NJ' as code, 'New Jersey' as name union all
        select 'NM' as code, 'New Mexico' as name union all
        select 'NY' as code, 'New York' as name union all
        select 'NC' as code, 'North Carolina' as name union all
        select 'ND' as code, 'North Dakota' as name union all
        select 'MP' as code, 'Northern Mariana Islands' as name union all
        select 'OH' as code, 'Ohio' as name union all
        select 'OK' as code, 'Oklahoma' as name union all
        select 'OR' as code, 'Oregon' as name union all
        select 'PW' as code, 'Palau' as name union all
        select 'PA' as code, 'Pennsylvania' as name union all
        select 'PR' as code, 'Puerto Rico' as name union all
        select 'RI' as code, 'Rhode Island' as name union all
        select 'SC' as code, 'South Carolina' as name union all
        select 'SD' as code, 'South Dakota' as name union all
        select 'TN' as code, 'Tennessee' as name union all
        select 'TX' as code, 'Texas' as name union all
        select 'UT' as code, 'Utah' as name union all
        select 'VT' as code, 'Vermont' as name union all
        select 'VI' as code, 'Virgin Islands' as name union all
        select 'VA' as code, 'Virginia' as name union all
        select 'WA' as code, 'Washington' as name union all
        select 'WV' as code, 'West Virginia' as name union all
        select 'WI' as code, 'Wisconsin' as name union all
        select 'WY' as code, 'Wyoming' as name
    ) states;
```